# How to Mirror Keyframes?

Tags: animation, bones, mirror

Okay, simple. I'm making a walk cycle for a quadruped creature, and I have just finished animating the Left Front Leg, how can I copy the Keyframes from the Left Leg onto the Right Leg? I know Maya can do this, so how can I do this in Blender?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> doesn't work.  It just copies exactly what I have onto the same bones, which is not what I want.

Comment: Are you selecting the opposite bones when pressing Shift + Ctrl + V? Also, this only pastes the pose, it doesn't create a keyframe so you should enable [Automatic keyframe insertion](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25931/understanding-automatic-key-frames-insertion)

Comment: Yes, I did all of that, and the Right Leg is still withouth animation. Just copies what i have already done and keeps it on the same Leg(same bones).

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, it's not necessary to select the opposite bones, but it is necessary that the bones have the same name and the sufix .R and .L for right and left respectively, for instance: forearm.R / forearm.L.

Comment: They do have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirroring a Keyframe is pretty easy. Go to "pose mode" and you must select all your bones including the ones you want to copy it to, then over in the right side of your screen will be three buttons

[image]

The first one is Copy

second Paste on same side

And the third is Paste on opposite side

With all your bones still selected press the first button to copy your pose you wish to be on the other side, then place it in the desired spot on the timeline by clicking the third button . This will mirror it to the left side(or opposite side) of your mesh.

If you want it a keyframe just click insert keyframe( with all bones still selected)

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: Check your bone names. In order for it to work, each side of your armature must have the same bone names with either left or right at the end of the bone name, indicating which side of the armature it is on.

Comment: I already know this, and all bones are named correctlly, the bones in the middle have no indicator.

Comment: Rotation and Location is a common issue for middle bones, if you are referring to the spinal bones that go down the middle of your figure. I have learned that when mirroring anything in edit mode or any mode, it tends to mirror from the middle of the axis. Middle bones are usually lined up in the middle of the axis. Its a little difficult to pin down the actual problem when I cannot see what the bones are doing, or in this case not doing. You could try looking into that. : )