# How to prevent imported animated glTF changing it's location

Tags: edit-mode

I have a large model (dock) and I import an animated glTF model which appears in the center of the large model (expected) and I then move it to where I want it.

I then select All and export as special MSFS glTF and after the export completes the animated model 'jumps' back to the position it was first in before I moved it.

I have all 'affect only' deselected in the Transform panel. What is causing it to move back to the original position?

I have noticed that when I select the imported animated glTF the transform location panel goes green. I have tried 'locking' the X, Y and Z axis after moving but that makes no difference.

Am I trying to do the impossible and I should import a non animated model and then add animation to just that part of the total model?
Here are 3 images to demonstrate what I mean. The first is of my dock with the animated model imported, the second is after I reposition the imported model and the third shows the model position after I export the entire model.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). You can rightclick the green fields and "clear keyframes". This will get rid of the animation.

Comment: Thanks Jachym. I don't want to get rid of the animation and wonder if the only way I can have an object/model which is not part of the main object/model animated is to import a non animated object (or 'clear keyframes' of an animated imported object) and then add animation?

Comment: OK I think I know what has happened.                                                                          The X,Y and W values in the keyframes are from the original imported animated object and so the X,Y and W values need to be updated in the keyframes from the position after moving the imported object). I can do that manually (3 values at 5 keyframes) BUT is there an easier method rather then manually entering (15 X 5 numerics)???

Comment: Hi :). I'm no animator, but these could help: [Understanding automatic key frames insertion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/25931/78972), [Object moves back into origin everytime i open the blender file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141410/78972)

Comment: Thanks Jachym. It was interesting to view those links and I have learned a bit more but could not work out if they helped me. I will 'answer your question' to hopefully close this thread as I think the easiest method for me is to import a static model and enter my animation again. It is my animated model so I know the 5 keyframe values. If it had been someone else's animated model with lots more keyframes it would have been difficult.   I still wonder if there is an easy method to 'paste' the location values to all the keyframes as Blender seems to have covered everything.

Comment: You could create an empty  parent the plane to the empty, and move the empty.

Comment: Thanks scurest. Not about creating a blank parent (I have only ever unparented objects) but I will check for video tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out that the keyframes of the imported animated model contain the original location values which do not change when the model is dragged to a new location
As it seems that there is no easy method to copy the location values to the keyframes after moving an animated model I have decided to 'clear keyframes' and enter them again so that the model remains in the location I dragged it to.
I had hoped there was a method to automatically change the location values (X, Y, W) in the animation after dragging to a new location